# react native map animations callback (such as animateToRegion)

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

#### Is there a callback when animation such as `animateToRegion` ends?

I use this

```
this.mapView.root.animateToRegion(newRegion, 500);
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't seems to at this moment : [Issue 1237](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/issues/1237)

> It seems there's no such callback in animateToCoordinates , runCommand calls NativeModules.UIManager which is JAVA module with synchronus behaviour . So , setTimeOut for 500 ms is the only way to go .